# 401 Error when connecting Cloud Pak For Data to mysql database

Tags: mysql, ibm-cloud, cloud-pak-for-data

When attempting to connect Cloud Pad to our mySQL db hosted by dreamhost, we were first getting a "error: invalid data: The assets request failed: CDICO0103E: Invalid username or password: dded error: [IBM][MySQL JDBC Driver][MySQL]Access denied for user '___'@'IP' (using password: YES) See the returned error to determine what action to take."

We attempted to open ports that were listed in this resource: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSTTDS_11.0.0/com.ibm.ace.cloud.doc/ip-addresses-outbound.html - this worked intermittently until it stopped working completely.

We have reproduced this issue on multiple computers including Windows and Mac Operating systems. We ran initially from different IP addresses to see if our local devices were having firewall issues. We have also used different browsers including Edge, Chrome, and Safari.

Comment: Access denied error suggests that you can connect to the mysql server, so there is nothing wrong with the ports. You just need to supply a correct username with the correct password.

Comment: @Shadow I was able to successfully connect and access the database with the current name and password so I know that the one I am using is correct. The issue is that it used to work almost at random when I tested the connection until it stopped working. All without a change in login info.